# Does order matter in multiplication of vector with symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

If we have $2$ vectors $p_1, p_2$ and a symmetric matrix $A$, is the following formula true in general, in some cases only or never? 
$$p^T_1 A p_2 = p^T_2 A p_1 $$

I made a test in a general case where $p_1 = \begin{bmatrix}r_1 \hspace{0.5cm} r_2\end{bmatrix}, p_2 = \begin{bmatrix}r_3 \hspace{0.5cm} r_4\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a&b \\b&c \end{bmatrix}$$
and the result is the same, but this isn't sufficient proof. Any insight would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: If $A$ is also positive definite, $\langle p_1, p_2\rangle_A = p_1^T A p_2^T$ defines an inner product. For inner products, $\langle p_1, p_2\rangle_A = \langle p_2, p_1\rangle_A$. I think if you take a larger indefinite matrix and it is possible that you will find a counter example.

Comment: It is indeed positive definite, didnt think it was important so didnt mention it. My bad. So it is always true in my case!

Comment: positivity is irrelevant.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas there is a one-to-one correspondence between matrices and bilinear forms.  A matrix is symmetric (in the sense of $A = A^T$) if and only if the bilinear form that it induces is symmetric (in the sense of $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle y,x \rangle$).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Indeed! That is an oversight on my part. I am going to edit my comment.

It looks like I can not edit my initial comment. As per Omnomnomnom's comment, $p_1^TAp_2 = B(p_1,p_2)$ is a bilinear form. Since the matrix $A$ is symmetric, the bilinear form $B$ is symmetric, i.e. $B(p_1,p_2) = B(p_2,p_1)$.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas too late for that I'm afraid but I'm sure these comments will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement will hold whenever $A$ is symmetric.  In particular, note that $p_1^TAp_2$ is a scalar (or a $1 \times 1$ matrix if you prefer), and any scalar is equal to its own transpose.  Thus,
$$
p_1^TAp_2 = (p_1^TAp_2)^T = p_2^TA^Tp_1 = p_2^TAp_1
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, i feel bad that this escaped me.. You are totally right

Comment: @Thomas I can speak from experience: if you enjoy learning about math, get used to feeling stupid along the way. Also, just because your question had a quick answer, doesn't mean that it was an easy question; this is a trick that I have gotten used to.

Comment: You're right :) Thanks for the encouragement. Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

There is a sort of trick, that a 1 by 1 matrix is always equal to its transpose: a number is always symmetric. If $AT = A,$ and $p,q$ are column vectors of the right size, then
$ q^T A p  $ is a one by one matrix, so it is equal to its transpose $p^TA^T q = p^TAq$

Comment: Oh god, you are definitely correct. I feel bad i didnt think about this, thanks